# (Python) Reading specific keys from json file

Tags: python, json

I have a question about how I can make this code work.
I have several json files, from which I must read information and store it in a pandas framework to export it later. The json files are pretty branched up and go something like this:
`'TESTS' -> 'MEASUREMENTS' -> SeveralTestNames(For each of those keys there is a key 'Value')` I need to get only the Values and save them.

My thought was, that I get the keys with the testnames, and then in a loop apply these names to the `json.load()`-method, but no matter what I try, it doesnt work.

```py
import json

with open(file) as f:
     data = json.load(f)
     date = data['INFO']['TIME'][0:10]
     time = data['INFO']['TIME'][11:]
     
     t = data['TESTS']['MEASUREMENTS']
     type = [*t]
 
     value = []
     i = 0
     for x in type:
         v = data['TESTS']['MEASUREMENTS'][type[i]]['RESULTS']
         value.append(v)
         i = i + 1
```

This just gives me 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str', but when I remove the last bit with the ['RESULTS'], it gives me the keys of the tests, but i need the values from within them.

Comment: Can you give an example of the `json` input as well as the expected output?

Comment: The ```type[i]``` should give me the names of the keys under the 'Measurements'-Key, the expected output is the Value stored in each of those testname-keys, for example ```147799000000```.
The json is like ```{'INFO':{'TIME','VERSION'}, 'TESTS': {'MEASUREMENTS':{ {'Test1':{'RESULTS':{'VALUE': 147799000000}}, 'Test1':{'RESULTS':{'VALUE': 147799000000}}...}}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're overcomplicating this for yourself a bit.

I'm reproducing your `json` from your comments as best as I can since parts of it are not valid `json`.

```
data = {
    'INFO': {
        'TIME': ' ',
        'VERSION' : ' '
    }, 
    'TESTS': {
        'MEASUREMENTS': { 
            'Test1': {
                'RESULTS': {
                    'VALUE': 147799000000
                }
            }, 
            'Test2': {
                'RESULTS': {
                    'VALUE': 147888278322
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
values = []
# this iterates over each dict within the MEASUREMENTS key
# dict.values() returns a view that you can iterate over
# of just the values
for measurement in data['TESTS']['MEASUREMENTS'].values():
    values.append(measurement['RESULTS']['VALUE'])
print(values)
```

In your case it would be:

```
import json

with open(file) as f:
     data = json.load(f)
values = []
for measurement in data['TESTS']['MEASUREMENTS'].values():
    values.append(measurement['RESULTS']['VALUE'])
print(values)
```